# How to make DOMPDF support unicode font step by step?

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, dompdf

I used DOMPDF library and now I have problem with content with unicode language. and I found this one [dompdf help](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/CPDFUnicode#Enable_the_MBString_PHP_extension)
but I don't understand about this. can anyone tell the detail of this?
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [DOMPDF problem with Cyrillic characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990181/dompdf-problem-with-cyrillic-characters)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Enable the [mbstring extension](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.setup.php)
2. Find a font in `.ttf` format with characters that support your given language
3. Generate a `.afm` file for DOMPDF:

   1. Using the command line, `cd` into the directory which contains `load_font.php`, then run `php load_font.php FontName /path/to/font.ttf`
   2. Using the [online tool](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/load_font.php), fill out the form and download the zip it  gives you. Copy the files from this zip into `dompdf/lib/fonts`. If you've done this before, add relevant lines to `dompdf_font_family_cache`, otherwise simply rename the `dompdf_font_family_cache.sample` to `dompdf_font_family_cache`
4. Enable DOMPDF's Unicode mode, by making sure the line

   ```
   define("DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED", true);
   ```

   is set in `dompdf_config.inc.php`. If it reads `false` instead of `true`, change that.

Comment: I got message:
**Unable to locate the ttf2afm / ttf2pt1 executable (checked /home/piseth/dev/example/pdf_php/lib/ttf2ufm/ttf2ufm-src/ttf2pt1).**

Comment: Sounds like you need to install tt2afm or tt2pt1. Try http://ttf2pt1.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I tried your instruction, but it doesn't work. I read in another topic  that I should add css about font family to the print.tpl and it really works then.

Comment: I followed the above instruction, but not work for me.

Comment: when i generate the pdf form html which contain burmese language( நான் என் முதலாளி வீட்டில் ஜன்னல்கள் வெளிப்புறம் சுத்தம் செய்ய தேவையில்லை என்று புரிந்துகொள்ளுங்கள் . ) then in pdf its show ???????????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: Any possibilities to display tamil content by using dompdf. I have used dompdf in codeigniter and trying to display tamil content but it showing 1.??? ????? ?????? ??????? any one can help me on this

Answer (score 3):

There is a [wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/CPDFUnicode) for this.

The next beta (0.6 beta 3), to be released soon, has a font installer that doesn't require the command line (neither any compilation).
You already can use it by checking out the [SVN trunk](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/source/checkout). This beta also supports `@font-face`.

Comment: The [SVN trunk](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/source/checkout) not work
I have `def("DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED", true);` change this also but still not work.

Comment: @user970587 it would help to see a sample of the code you're attempting to render (and more detail about what you've tried)

Answer (score 1):

As of version 0.7, dompdf supports and has unicode enabled by default. (therefore there is no need for configuration).

Not all dompdf fonts support unicode though. I used  `font-family: DejaVu Sans` with success.

To install a custom font or learn more about it you can read the official [unicode how to](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo).

Answer (score 1):

Download [load_font.php](https://github.com/dompdf/utils) and place in ur project root

View `load_font.php`

add `$fontDir = "storage/fonts";`

This will show where the fonts are added.

download your font at eg: PREETI and place at your project root

run in command line `php load_font.php PREETI PREETI.ttf`

then you font will be installed to `storage/fonts` directory

now go to the pdf file and add

```
<style>
    body {
        font-family: PREETI;
        color: #1c2221;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: run in command line php load_font.php PREETI PREETI.ttf=>how do I run this ..command in browser or in php program ... I want  to use in website pls help..command line is for window?..I wish to install for website

Answer (score -1):

try to manipulate your code using this recommended [DOMPDF method](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo) 
it's a A guide to enabling Unicode support in DOMPDF
To ensure maximum compatibility you should follow all of the following steps. Click through for additional details.

  `Ensure the MBString PHP extension is enabled
  Install dompdf 0.6.0 or greater
  Configure dompdf for Unicode support
  Load a font supporting your characters into dompdf
  Create a compatible HTML document`

    see the link for more information