# I Can't Find dompdf_config.inc.php or dompdf_config.custom.inc.php for setting "DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED" true

Tags: php, pdf, unicode, dompdf, persian

I use dompdf to save a html page as pdf by php. I use Persian characters in my html page (actually php page) but when i'm trying to save it as pdf, the export just looked like '?????' :( .I have searched all the net and I found a configuration for unicode characters  https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo#configure-dompdf-for-unicode-support in "**dompdf_config.inc.php**" or **"dompdf_config.custom.inc.php"** file. but the problem is I CAN'T FIND such file in all of my dompdf folder and in all of my file system. Please somebody tell me where it is or what I must do. something else is that I have to use dompdf because of its fantastic CSS compatibility. Thanks.

This is Export.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYAzW.png

This is my code.

```
require("dompdf/autoload.inc.php");
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml("<html><head>
<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;charset=utf-8\">

<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"styles/scorestyle.css\">

</head>
<body><div>
<div id=\"showscorediv\"><table><tbody><tr class=\"scoresubject\"><th colspan=\"2\">کارنامه ارزیابی</th></tr><tr class=\"scorecategory\"><th>شاخص ها</th><th>امیتاز ها</th></tr><tr><td><span class=\"level_0\">شاخص های کیفی</span></td><td class=\"scoretd\">62</td></tr><tr><td><span class=\"level_1\">شاخص های مرتبط با تیم کاری</span></td><td class=\"scoretd\">10</td></tr><tr><td><span class=\"level_1\">شاخص های مرتبط با محصول</span></td><td class=\"scoretd\">28</td></tr><tr><td><span class=\"level_1\">شاخص های مرتبط با بازار</span></td><td class=\"scoretd\">24</td></tr><tr><td><span class=\"level_0\">شاخص های کمی</span></td><td class=\"scoretd\">60</td></tr><tr><td><span class=\"level_1\">شاخص های تولیدی</span></td><td class=\"scoretd\">20</td></tr><tr><td><span class=\"level_1\">شاخص های درآمدی</span></td><td class=\"scoretd\">14</td></tr><tr><td><span class=\"level_1\">شاخص های هزینه ای</span></td><td class=\"scoretd\">26</td></tr><tr class=\"scoresubject\"><th>امتیاز کل</th><th>122</th></tr></tbody></table>
</div>
</div></body></html>");
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream();
```

Comment: Maybe you need to download those. I  do not know, just guessing by intuition.

Comment: where should I place it @LajosArpad after downloading those files? I mean which address?

Comment: It seems that you need to put the custom config file into the root folder: https://github.com/rposborne/gravityformspdf/blob/master/dompdf/dompdf_config.custom.inc.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using dompdf 0.7.0, which no longer uses the dompdf_config.inc.php configuration file. Unicode support is always enabled with this release.

To display the characters used in your sample code you need to ensure that:

1. You are supplying a font that supports these characters (that [appears to be the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182619/i-cant-find-dompdf-config-inc-php-or-dompdf-config-custom-inc-php-for-setting#comment61904932_37185333)).
2. That dompdf has both read and write capability to the temporary directory, font directory, and font cache directory. You can set these using `$dompdf->set_option('option', 'value');` (where option would be `tempDir`, `fontDir`, or `fontCache`).
3. The font is accessible to dompdf and is in TTF format.
4. You are correctly styling your content to use your font. Hard to know without seeing your CSS.

FYI, you can't just drop the TTF/UFM in your font directory. dompdf has to record information about the font in order to use it. Also, the AFM metrics file won't work in this case anyway because that indicates Windows ANSI encoding on the font. Windows ANSI encoding does not support the characters in your sample. Dompdf uses the UFM metrics format for Unicode support.

The utilities that were included with previous versions of dompdf are no longer included with 0.7.0. So long as you meet the requirements of using the `@font-face` declaration you don't need any external utilities. If needed, however, you can find a compatible version of the load_font.php script in the [dompdf-utils project](https://github.com/dompdf/utils).

Since you are using 0.7.0 (which was just released) a lot of info on the Internet may be out of date, so you may want to read up on how to use it:

- [dompdf README](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/v0.7.0/README.md)
- [dompdf 0.7.0 release notes](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases/tag/v0.7.0)
- [dompdf wiki](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki) (pay attention to any versioning information)

---

Lastly, dompdf includes a font (DejaVu) that can support your characters. Try adding the following to your stylesheet so that you have a fallback in case your custom font doesn't work:

```
* { font-family: BZar_0, DejaVu Sans, sans-serif; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just added dompdf_config.inc.php and dompdf_config.custom.inc.php files from dompdf 0.6.2 version, besides include dir with autoload.inc.php and functions.inc.php to my dompdf 0.8.* and it works.

Answer (score 0):

To set any DOMPDF option you have to define a named constant.
All available options can be found here: http://pxd.me/dompdf/www/setup.php

To enable Persian characters you basically have to enable unicode support.

```
define("DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED", true);
```

You may want to set `DOMPDF_FONT_DIR` and `DOMPDF_DEFAULT_FONT` as well, just to make sure that the font you're using supports unicode characters.

Comment: where should I put this constant?You mean in my main code?I did this nothing changed.

Comment: this is my code : <?php
require("dompdf/autoload.inc.php");
define("DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED", true);
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml(mb_convert_encoding("فارسی", 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'Portrait');

$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream();

Comment: you man want to use this tutorial to add a font to DOMPDF before you use it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968627/how-to-make-dompdf-support-unicode-font-step-by-step

you can use more detailed tutorial here:
https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo

Comment: I add my font by css font face because i can`t find load_font.php anywhere and the online tool for that is shutdown. what should I do??

Comment: You can use any tool that lets you convert `*.ttf` files into `*.amf`.
Here's an online one: https://everythingfonts.com/ttf-to-afm

Comment: I coverted .ttf to .afm and put in dompdf\lib\fonts and its name is BZar_0.afm. Also my code for changing font is =>> use Dompdf\Options; $options = new Options();
$options->set('defaultFont', 'BZar_0');
$dompdf = new Dompdf($options); //nothing changed :-(

Comment: Does the html of yours contain `<meta />` tag similar to this one: 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>`?

Comment: yes you can see that in the question. I think this is because of dompdf_config.inc.php and dompdf_config.custom.inc.php . It doesn't have been downloaded while I clone it from git. I don't know why!!!!?? where should I download it and which directory should i put it? thanks a lot.