# PHP Utf8 Decoding Issue

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I have the following address line: **Praha 5, Staré Město,**

I need to use utf8_decode() function on this string before I can write it to a PDF file (using domPDF lib).

However, the php utf8 decode function for the above address line appears incorrect (or rather, incomplete).

The following code:

```
<?php echo utf8_decode('Praha 5, Staré Město,'); ?>
```

Produces this:

> Praha 5, Staré M?sto,

Any idea why **ě** is not getting decoded?

Comment: utf8_decode simply converts a string encoded in UTF-8,is your string is utf8_encoded ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`utf8_decode` *converts* the string from a UTF-8 encoding to ISO-8859-1, a.k.a. "Latin-1".
The Latin-1 encoding cannot represent the letter "ě". It's that simple.
"Decode" is a total misnomer, it does the same as `iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $string)`.

See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Comment: Thanks the best answer (2015) +1

Comment: @deceze `utf8_decode converts the string from a UTF-8 encoding to ISO-8859-1`


This saved me probably couple of hours! would gladly buy you a drink if you were in our office :)

Answer (score 1):

I wound up using a home-grown UTF-8 / UTF-16 decoding function (convert to &#number; representations), I haven't found any pattern to why UTF-8 isn't detected, I suspect it's because the "encoded-as" sequence isn't always exactly in the same position in the string returned. You might do some additional checking on that.

Three-character UTF-8 indicator: $startutf8 = chr(0xEF).chr(187).chr(191); (if you see this ANYWHERE, not just first three characters, the string is UTF-8 encoded)

Decode according to UTF-8 rules; this replaced an earlier version which chugged through byte by byte:using

```
function charset_decode_utf_8 ($string) {
/* Only do the slow convert if there are 8-bit characters */
/* avoid using 0xA0 (\240) in ereg ranges. RH73 does not like that */
if (! ereg("[\200-\237]", $string) and ! ereg("[\241-\377]", $string))
    return $string;

// decode three byte unicode characters
$string = preg_replace("/([\340-\357])([\200-\277])([\200-\277])/e",       
"'&#'.((ord('\\1')-224)*4096 + (ord('\\2')-128)*64 + (ord('\\3')-128)).';'",   
$string);

// decode two byte unicode characters
$string = preg_replace("/([\300-\337])([\200-\277])/e",
"'&#'.((ord('\\1')-192)*64+(ord('\\2')-128)).';'",
$string);

return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in your PHP file encoding , save your file in  `UTF-8` encoding , then even no need to use `utf8_decode` , if you get these data `'Praha 5, Staré Město,'` from database , better change it charset to `UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

you don't need that (@Rajeev :this string is automatically detected as utf-8 encoded :

```
echo mb_detect_encoding('Praha 5, Staré Město,');
```

will always return UTF-8.).

You'd rather see :
https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/CPDFUnicode

Comment: I removed the utf8_decode and set <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> and also DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED is set to true in config. However, it does not work, ě appears as ?

Comment: I am using the 'Helvetica' font, could that be why?

Comment: you may have to install another font. Check the answers here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990181/dompdf-problem-with-cyrillic-characters