# Utf8 not translating certain characters with PHP

Tags: php, utf-8

Here are the encodings/charsets :

MySQL field is latin1_swedish_ci
HTML charset is ISO-8559-1

Using utf8_decode to output, since the characters are UTF-8.  So there should be no problem.. BUT...

All the "usual" accented characters are showing up fine—however we are having problems with the following :

Š = doesn't show up

œ = shows up as ? (ligatures)

Anyway ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you add `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` before you output the characters?

Comment: If I change the charset, then all the other content is screwed up.  The Š and the œ are technically utf8 so it SHOULD work.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17211131/2518525) could possibly be related..?

Comment: I think you're right... in fact, if I could go back and change the MySQL collation to unicode and the page to utf-8, then I'm sure everything would be fine.  However, the client won't pay for that so I'm trying to find a workaround.

Comment: In your linked question, the guy says :  "The Latin-1 encoding cannot represent the letter "ě". It's that simple."  However, isn't that the whole point of encoding translations?