# Cyrillic symbols in DOMPDF

Tags: php, drupal, utf-8, pdf-generation, dompdf

I used this post to provide a proper Ukrainian symbols in my Invoice. [I use Drupal 7, module Commerce Billy and Commerce Billy PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990181/dompdf-problem-with-cyrillic-characters/34182048). They work with DOMPDF.

the main thing I achieved after these silutions, I have only 2 related errors. But no Ukrainian or Russian in PDF.

The errors are following,

> Notice: Undefined index: /sites/all/libraries/dompdf/lib/fonts/DejaVuSans in Text_Renderer->render() (line 91 from /sites/all/libraries/dompdf/include/text_renderer.cls.php). Notice: Undefined index: /sites/all/libraries/dompdf/lib/fonts/DejaVuSans in Text_Renderer->render() (line 91 from /sites/all/libraries/dompdf/include/text_renderer.cls.php).

There are only Latinic symbols in PDF

How can I solve it?

Comment: The error seems to indicate an odd font name ("DejaVuSans в"), what does your HTML and CSS look like?

Comment: <code>     <html>
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
   <p>test</p>
   <p>тест</p>
   <p><?php print ('testtesttest'); ?></p>
  </body>
</html>
</code>

Comment: "в" means "in". it's my mistake in creating an issue. I use localization and it translates string

Comment: Ah, thanks for correcting my misunderstanding. I guess I should have been able to deduce that from the context.

Comment: The DejaVu fonts are included with dompdf starting with 0.6.0. The message seems to indicate that CPDF (the back end in use) is unable to find the font file. Does the font file exist in the specified location?

Comment: Does the executing process have read access to that file? Or perhaps it's a [case issue with the file path/name](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1002)? I dunno where to go from here. It might help to see the source HTML and relevant PHP. You also might try enabling dompdf debugging to see if you get any useful messages related to loading the font.